# How can I replace an NA value in a column for something if I have an specific value in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

Using tidyr I want to modify a dataframe. Basically in this dataframe I have a column with different type of products: Fruits, Vegetables, Meat, etc... Let's call it the "Group" column.

In the same dataframe I have another column with the label of the product: Fruits and Vegetables products, Farm products, Fresh products... Let's call it the "Label" column.

What I'm trying to do is to replace the NA values of the Group column depending on the result of the Label column. For example: if the Label column shows "Farm products" then I want to replace the NA value of the Group column by the value "Milk". While if the Label column shows "Fruits and Vegetables products", I want the NA value of the Group column to take the value "Vegetables".

For this I've been trying to use the following code:

```
data_ES$Group <- data_ES$Group %>%
  replace_na('Vegetables', if(data_ES$Label = "Fruits and Vegetables products"))
```

Of course this doesn't work because is just the intuition I have, I'm very new at programming.

Can somebody give me hints or ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded a little example, for what I guess is what you are searching for:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Group = c(NA,"Fruits","Vegetables",NA,"Meat"),
             Label = c("Fruits and Vegetables products",
                       "Fruits and Vegetables products",
                       "Fruits and Vegetables products",
                       "Farm products","Farm products" ))

df_replaced <- df %>% mutate(Group  = case_when(Label == "Fruits and Vegetables products" & is.na(Group)    
                                            ~ "Vegetables",
                                            Label == "Farm products" & is.na(Group) ~ "Milk",
                                            TRUE ~ Group))
```

Comment: You also need to check for NA before replacing.

Comment: Thanks! Your anwser is very helpful. I think is the right path to follow. There is a little issue though. Now every other value of my Group column becomes NA. I want to keep everything as it is except for the NA values. When I use your example everything becomes NA except for the values I specify. My dataframe is pretty complex... But I'm pretty sure I will be able to go further thanks to you!

Comment: I just edited my answer. Does it help?

Comment: It does! Is exactly what I needed. Thank you!